# How can i set a row in a gt table to be a specific color

Tags: r, colors, gt

So, for example in the table below, I want to make the background color for the third row #D9654B.
 It can be done either by specifying the third row or making it conditional on V1=="c"

```
df <- tibble(V1=c("a","b","c"),V2=c(7:9))
df %>% 
  gt()
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `tab_style` to target specific cells for formatting

```
df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "#D9654B")
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = vars(V1, V2), # not needed if coloring all columns
      rows = 3)
  )
```

[image]

If you like specifying the value of `V1` better that works too, just use `rows = V1 == "c"`

Comment: Much appreciated. It appears as though you do not need to specify columns at all if you want the whole row one color

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

tab_options(data, table.border.bottom.width= px(0))