# Add a color column based on the values from other column

Tags: r, gt

I am trying to add color to a column based on its values. I have a column named Class with two values `instructor` and `student`. I want to give a black color to the `instructor` and green color to `student`.

I have tried the following:

```
library(gt)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Class = ifelse(as.character(Class) == "instructor", "black", "green")) %>% 
  gt() %>%
  data_color(columns = Class,
             colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c("black", "green"), domain = c(0.2E7, 0.4E7)
      ))
```

I am using the `data_color()` method from the `gt()` https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/data_color.html package but gives me the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("rescale") : 
no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "character"
```

data:

```
Class
-----
student
student
student
instructor
student
instructor
....
```

Is there a way that I can add a color value or put a color to a column in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do it. Here I first find the columns that should be colored (using the `which()`-function) and then telling `tab_style()`the just found locations.

This link [Set row color (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510251/how-can-i-set-a-row-in-a-gt-table-to-be-a-specific-color) might also help.

```
library(gt)
# example data
df<-data.frame(Class=c("student","student","student","instructor","student","instructor"))

## find positions of "instructor"
index1<-which(df$Class=="instructor")
## find positions of "student"
index2<-which(df$Class=="student")

df %>% gt() %>%
  tab_style(
    style=list(
      cell_fill(color="green")
    ),
    locations= cells_body(
      rows=index1
    )
  ) %>%
  tab_style(
    style=list(
      cell_fill(color="lightblue")
    ),
    locations= cells_body(
      rows=index2
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this answer with comments. This helps!